# strtol の restrict 修飾について

Tags: c

時に、以下のようなプログラム(プログラム自体は特に意味は無いです)を見かけます。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *input = "1 5 9 2 6 4 8";
    int array[16];

    char *p = input;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 16 && *p; ++i){
        array[i] = strtol(p, &p, 10);
    }
    for(int n = i, i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

気になるのは、`strtol(p, &p, 10)` の部分です。

`strtol` のプロトタイプを見ると、

```
long strtol(
    const char * restrict nptr,
    char ** restrict endptr
    int base
);
```

のようになっていて、
第１引数と第２引数にrestrict修飾がされています。
私のざっくりとした理解ではそれは関数内でその引数を使う時に他の引数とかぶってはいけない(同じオブジェクト指すようなものであってはいけない)ということです。（つまり、私の理解では、制約違反。理解が間違っている場合そこら辺も解説して欲しいです。）
この場合、restrict制約に違反していることになるのでしょうか？

それとも型が違うのだから大丈夫？
型が違うから大丈夫なら、そもそも２つの引数にrestrict修飾する必要などないのでは？
逆に、このケースでrestrict制約違反になる場合とはどんな場合？

あと、
restrict制約に違反するようなプログラムを書いた場合、
それはすなわち動作未定義ですか？（例えば第一引数はconstでオブジェクトを変更しないことが明らかなので実質問題無いように思える）

---

(他に書く所がないのでここで)
コメントで、`memcpy(p, p, 0)` が動作未定義かどうか？
ということを書いたのですが、
規格のサンプルで、

```
void h(int n, int * restrict p, int * restrict q, int * restrict r)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    p[i] = q[i] + r[i];
}
```

の場合、

> h(100, a, b, b) has defined behavior, because array b is not modified within function h.

って書いてある。
(この場合第１引数と第２・３引数との制約で、第２と第３引数の間の制約ではないとも言える。)
理由として変更がされないからということであれば、
動作未定義かどうかは単にパラメータ(のポインタが同一オブジェクトを指すかどうか)だけでは（実装を知らない使用者側としては）判断ができずに、その実装によることになる。（実際には動作の説明が必要不可欠）
（逆に言えば、未定義動作(期待しないような動作)するような状況になったら、動作未定義だったのだなとわかるｗ）
だから、`memcpy(p, p, 0)`の場合も、明らかに変更するような動作が行われないので、defined behaviorだと言える。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

前提：C99の`restrict`キーワードは「処理系に対する最適化のためのヒント情報」であり、**妥当(valid)な** Cソースコードから全ての`restrict`キーワードを削除しても、プログラムの意味は変化しません[C99 §6.7.3.1/3]。またrestrict修飾を理解するには、前提知識として [Strict Aliasing Rules(厳密な別名付けの規則)](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-exp39-c.html) を理解している必要があります。同規則については [packet0さん回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29673/29709#29709) に説明がありますが、大まかには次の通りです：

- C言語コンパイラは、非互換な型へのポインタ同士は互いにaliasでないと仮定したコード生成を行ってよい。
- ただし文字型へのポインタ型(`char*`)だけは、任意の型とのaliasを仮定する必要がある。

これらはalias解析に関するコンパイル時最適化を許可する規則であり、プログラマはStrict Aliasing Rulesを遵守したコードを記述する義務があります。`restrict`キーワードは、本来の規則ではaliasを仮定せざるをえないケース（互換型へのポインタや`char*`）に対して、最適化を促すヒント情報「このポインタ値についてはaliasを考慮しなくてよい」をコンパイラに伝える仕組みです。

---

> 気になるのは、`strtol(p, &p, 10)`の部分です。
>   （中略）
>   この場合、restrict制約に違反していることになるのでしょうか？

いいえ。

- 第1引数`p`は、`char`型オブジェクトの配列(文字列リテラル)を指す指すポインタ値です。
- 第2引数`&p`は、`char*`型オブジェクト(変数`p`)を指すポインタ値です。

上記の2個のポインタ値は異なるオブジェクトを指します／互いにaliasではありませんから、関数呼び出し`strtol(p, &p, 10)`はwell-definedです。

> それとも型が違うのだから大丈夫？
>   型が違うから大丈夫なら、そもそも２つの引数にrestrict修飾する必要などないのでは？

Strict Aliasing Rulesでも`char*`は特別扱いされますから、restrict修飾によって初めて「第1仮引数`nptr`と第2仮引数`endptr`は互いにaliasではない」ことを表明します。ただし、ここで関数`strtol`の引数がrestrict修飾されているのは、**C標準ライブラリ実装者のため** です。アプリケーションプログラマにとってはメリットもデメリットもほぼありません（詳細後述）。

ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG14より[C99仕様策定時のRationale(論理的根拠)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf)が公開されており、§7にてC標準ライブラリにおける`restrict`キーワード利用指針が触れられています。関数`strtol`のケースに適用できる説明を引用します：

> Since the implementation costs are high if vendors are forced to cater to this extremely rare case, the `restrict` keyword is used to explicitly forbid situations like these.
>
> Another library routine that uses `restrict` is:
>
> ```
> char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> Again, since a character pointer can be a potential alias with other pointers, `restrict` is used to make it clear to the translator that parameter `s` is never an alias with parameter `stream` when the `fgets` function is called in a strictly conforming program.

C標準ライブラリのうち`char*`型とそれ以外のポインタ型を引数にとる関数では、上記理由によりrestrict修飾がされています。

> 逆に、このケースでrestrict制約違反になる場合とはどんな場合？

下記のような偏執的コードを書いたときです。関数`strtol`のセマンティクス上このような処理は一般的でないため、アプリケーションプログラマにとって関数`strtol`でのrestrict修飾有無は影響がありません：

```
char a[] = “123456789”;
char** p = (char**)(&a[0]); // 配列aの一部をchar*オブジェクトとみなす
strtol(a, p, 10);
```

---

> restrict制約に違反するようなプログラムを書いた場合、それはすなわち動作未定義ですか？

Strict Aliasing Rulesおよびrestrict修飾に関して、aliasに関する規則に違反したプログラムは未定義動作です。

> コメントで、`memcpy(p, p, 0)`が動作未定義かどうか？

これはwell-definedです。関数`memcpy`の第3引数に値`0`を指定した場合、ゼロ文字のコピー動作つまり何もしないことが保証されます[C99 §7.21.1/2]。関数`memcpy`が未定義動作を引き起こすのは、2つのポインタ値引数が指す領域のうち実際にオーバーラップしている部分でコピーが行われたときです[C99 §7.21.2.1/2]。

Answer (score 4):

サンプルが`restrict`制約の対象になら無いのは[Tatz Sekineさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/29682/3974)通りだと思います。

`restrict`修飾が付いている理由は推測でしか無いのですが、以下のようなことが考えられると思います（でも`endptr`へ書き込んだ後に`nptr`を読み込まないと思うので`restrict`やエイリアス関係無いと思うんですよね…）。

---

Strict Aliasing(厳密な別名)規約によると、同じオブジェクトへの参照は以下のような型としてでしかしてはならない、とあります。逆に同スコープ内にこれらの型がある場合`restrict`を付けなければエイリアスが想定されることになると思います。

C99; ISO/IEC 9899:1999 6.5/7より (括弧内は自分がつけた訳です):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - **a type compatible with the effective type of the object (オブジェクトと互換性のある型)**,
> - a qualiﬁed version of a type compatible with the effective type of
>   the object (修飾された互換性のある型),
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the
>   effective type of the object (オブジェクトの符号あり・なし版),
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a
>   qualiﬁed version of the effective type of the object (修飾されたオブジェクトの符号あり・なし版),
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned
>   types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union) (上記4つをメンバに持つstruct/union/array), or
> - **a character type (char型)**.
>
> The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.

1つ目にある「Compatible Type」の一覧は規格書内に見つからなかったのですが、[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/type#Compatible_types)によると以下を含むそうです (括弧内は同上):

- they are pointer types and are pointing to compatible types (互換性のある型へのポインタ)

なので`strtol`の2つの変数はデフォルトではエイリアスが想定されるのだと思います。

もう1つ、最後の項目によると、`char`として参照すると(`nptr[i]`や`*nptr`でしょうか)問答無用で他のどの型ともエイリアスがありえると解釈できるので、↑の他にこちらも`restrict`が付いている理由といえる気がします（個人的に初耳なので違うような気も）。

---

追記
`restrict`はエイリアスを防止するわけではなく、プログラマ**が**コンパイラ**に対して**エイリアスが無い事を**約束**するための修飾です。なのでコンパイラはそのつもりで最適化して良いですが、コードによっては関係無い場合もあります。ただrestrictした上で、同じオブジェクトを「変数1」で読み、「変数2」で書き込み、さらにもう1度「変数1」で読むとほぼ確実に期待とは違った結果になります（別のオブジェクトだと思い2度目の読み込みに1度目の結果を使い回すため）。

質問に追記された関数`h(100, a, b, b)`が問題無いのは書き込まれる変数`p`と読み込まれる変数`q`、`r`が別なためで、`h(100, a, a, b)`とかでは仕様的にはダメだと思います（でも読み込みが先で、書き込んだ後に読まないので期待通りに動きそう）。`memcpy(p, p, 0)`は何もしないのでOKかもしれませんが`memcpy(p, p+1, 10)`とかはアウトです。
そこの厳密なdefinedのラインはすみませんが分かりません。

あと、標準ライブラリでの`restrict`の使われ方を見ていると、実装の話より、ユーザーに対してエイリアスの良し悪しを伝えるために付けているような気もします（本来の意図と違う）。実際`strtol`はエイリアスがあっても大丈夫なように実装できますし、`memmove`もglibcなどの実装は書き込んだ領域を読まないので`restrict`が付いていても期待通りの動作をすると思います。ですが`memmove`は機能的に読み書きの領域がかぶっても良いので`restrict`とは逆の振る舞いであり、だから修飾されていないのだと思います。

最後に、コメントに書かれたように`restrict`は引数である必要はなく、普通の変数にも使えます。

Comment: つまり、restrict制約とは同一スコープ内のエイリアスによるアクセスを防止する。ということで、必ずしも引数同士に対する制約ではないということですね。（別スレッドからのアクセスがないことを保証する的な？(シングルスレッドだと関数の終了まで他からのアクセスのしようがない)） でもそうだとすると、memmoveのような(memcpyはrestrictが付くがmemmoveは付かない)ものにもrestrict制約が必要になるように思います。

Comment: オブジェクトの参照という意味では、単なる型が違うというのではダメで、`*nptr` と `**endptr`は同じオブジェクトを指すわけで、そういう意味（オブジェクトの参照（可能性？））で互換性のある型ということになるんじゃないかと思いますが・

Comment: @BLUEPIXY さん、長くなるので回答に追記しました。

Comment: 確認ですが、関数の引数におけるrestrict制約はやはり引数同士における制約ですよね？

Comment: 同じスコープであれば関数内の変数と引数を区別したりはしないと思います。シンプルに`restrict`がついた変数が指すオブジェクトはその変数でしか読み書きされないと仮定して、ほかによって値が変わった可能性は考えずに最適化するのでは無いでしょうか。個人的に関数内に`static char * restrict ptr`の様なstatic変数があると現実的にはまりそうかなとおもいます。

Comment: FYI: _compatible type_ はC99 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite typeにて定義されます。また標準ライブラリでの`restrict`キーワード利用指針は、[C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) page 109-111にて詳細に解説されています。

Answer (score 1):

`strtol` の第一引数は `char` (とその後ろに連続してある char) へのポインター (i.e. input へのポインター) であり、第2引数は `char *` へのポインター (i.e. p へのポインター) です。よってそれぞれのポインターが指してる先は別のオブジェクトなので、restirct 制約に違反してないように見えます。restrict 制約は、そのポインターが指してる先しか影響しない（ポインターのポインターだからといって、ポインターの先のまた先を見ない）はずです。

手元に規格書がないのですが、https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict によれば

> If the declaration of intent is not followed and the object is
>   accessed by an independent pointer, this will result in undefined
>   behavior.

と書いてあるので、制約に違反するプログラムの動作は未定義のようです。

**追記**
そもそも型が違う時点で `restrict` は意味無いでしょう。 http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yohhoy/20120223/p1 によれば

> なお「異なる型へのポインタ型同士」の場合は、restrictキーワードによる指示がなくてもstrict aliasing ruleに基づいて、コンパイラは互いに他方のaliasにならないと仮定した最適化を行う。

とありますし。意味があるかどうかはおいておくとして、無理やり

```
int main(void) {
  char *p = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char *));
  p[0] = '0';
  p[1] = '\0';
  long l = strtol(p, (char **) p, 10);
```

とすれば、`restrict` 制約に反するコードになるかもしれません。

Comment: charへのポインタとcharへのポインタへのポインタで指しているのが別オブジェクトであるから大丈夫ということならば、そういうケースではrestrict制約はそもそも必要無い（違反のなりようがない）ように思えます。このケースで違反になるケースはどのようなものですか？

Comment: 後半部分について、例えば`memcpy(p, p, 0)`のような場合明らかに同一ポインタを引数にしているので、制約違反のように思えますが、コピー要素数が０なので、実際にはオブジェクトへのアクセスが明らかにないと思われます。この場合は制約違反ですか？

Comment: 型が違っても`restrict`が意味を持つケースは存在します。引用URLの[関連記事](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yohhoy/20120229)で少し触れているのですが、Strict Aliasing Rulesでも文字型(`char*`)だけ特殊扱いしており、異なる型であってもaliasを仮定せざるをえません（≒最適化の対象外）。このケースでは`char * restrict`のように明示的にaliasが無いことを通知する意味があります。